# How can I prove this property of root's multiplicity, for also non-polynomial function?

Tags: calculus

I have this definition of multiplicity of a root:

> A root $x_0$ of the equation $F(x)=0$ has multiplicity k if $F^{k-1}(x_0)=0$ but $F^{[k]}(x_0)\neq 0$. Here $F^{[k]}$ is the $k^{th}$ derivative of $F$ and $F^{[0]}=F$.

From: L. Devaney, A first course in chaotic dynamical systems

I want to demonstrate that also the derivatives from [1] to [k-2] in $x_0$ are 0. How can I prove this property for also non-polynomial function?

My ultimate aim is demonstrate that if $x_0$is a root of multiplicity k for F, then F(x) may be written in the form $F(x)=(x-x_0)^{k}G(x)$.

Comment: Take F(x)=\sin(x). You have F(0)=0 and F^{''}(0)=0 too, but F'(0) is not zero

Comment: @Idris Sorry, I don't understand your answer.

Comment: M'y example shows that what you are trying to prove is not true

Comment: @Idris $0$ is not a multiple root of $f(x)=\sin x$.

Comment: The définition of multiplicity Known to me is that all the derivatives untill k are zero but not the next one

Comment: @Idris Check this https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjC3vi8mNbJAhUNH44KHSTJDXQQygQILzAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMultiplicity_(mathematics)%23Multiplicity_of_a_root_of_a_polynomial&usg=AFQjCNH2jqMJwFyiK5Lz5ECHmQ6RjXm16w

Comment: @Idris What do you mean by "until $k$"? Are you referring to $f, f', f'', ... , f^{(k)}$?

Comment: @YiyuanLee yes it is

Comment: @Aniket let me tell that i agree with you

Comment: According to the définition provided in the question, m'y example gives a function which has 0 as a root of multiplicity Two since F(0)=F"(0)=0 and F'''(0) is not zero. However F'(0) is not zero, so what Detry try to prove is not true

Comment: Then by your definition, $f^{(0)} = 0$ but $f^{(1)} \not = 0$,  so $x = 0$ has multiplicity $0$. I think your definition is erroneous or lacking something crucial.

Comment: @Idris Your definition of multiplicity cannot exist with the existence of fixed point of the Newton–Raphson's function associated with sinx. This happens according to Newton's fixed point theorem (from my book: Newton–Raphson's associated function ammits fixed point $x_0$ if and only if $x_0$ is a root with multiplicity).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Thanks to [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), we can express almost all non-polynomial functions as polynomial functions. However one must check beforehand whether the function at all possesses multiple roots.

Comment: I've already tried your way. The terms of Taylor,  without considering the first one, have the factor $(x-x_0)$. So, when I tried to study the function exactly in the root $x_0$, all the terms vanished: i can't get new information about the derivatives in $x_0 $.

Comment: @Detry By Taylor, actually I mean its simpler form i.e. the Maclaurin series. Have you tried that?